# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ill afb'

Tags: python-3.7

Read in our data from a CSV file and create a dictionary of records, where the key is a unique record ID.

```
def readData(filename):

    data_d = {}

    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            clean_row = dict([(k, preProcess(v)) for (k, v) in row.items()])
            if clean_row['BUSINESS_LOCATION_ID']:
                clean_row['BUSINESS_LOCATION_ID'] = float(clean_row['BUSINESS_LOCATION_ID'][1:])

            data_d[filename + str(i)] = dict(clean_row)

    return data_d
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ill afb'

Comment: So there is a value "ill afb" in your CSV value in the BUSINESS_LOCATION_ID column.

Comment: Seems odd that a location *id* is a floating point number, by the way.

Comment: BUSINESS_LOCATION_ID it is an integer column but when i'm running the same error is showing me everytime.

Comment: That'll be because not all values in that column are actually integers; one is the string "ill afb". I guess your input CSV file is badly formatted. You should try to load parts of your CSV file each time, and bisect it to find the problematic line(s).

Comment: If it's an integer column, I'm not sure why you convert it to a float (which are much more inconvenient to use as an ID), but that's up to you then.